# Raspberry Pi + Windows 10 IoT Core + RS485

Tags: pi-2, hardware, windows-iot, c#, signal

Has somebody ever worked with windows 10 IoT Core and used RS485?

I would like to receive some signals from the RS485 device.

I would like to do this with Windows universal app.

Comment: Hi ARcihter, Thanks for posting. Please do not use signatures in your post because there is already one, the one on the bottom left with your score :) I have formatted your question a little bit and some grammar. I hope you don't mind. I think your question is very interesting and hopefully possible.